# DC motor speed reduction

Tags: motor, dc-motor, speed

I have a 4 pole DC mobility scooter motor but no controller. I want to use it to run a small mechanical hacksaw.  The motor on a 12 volt battery is powerful enough but is too fast. I have seen plenty of reducers on the net, but will these work with a 4 pole motor?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please explain more! Is it a true brushed shunt or series DC motor? DC input via inbuilt three phase driver to an asynchronous three phase inductor motor, i.e. “brushless DC”? What have you tried so far and what happened?

Comment: Have you heard of gear boxes?

Comment: It's a mobility scooter motor but I have no other parts.the motor runs great when connected to a small 12 volt battery direct but is too fast for my application

Answer (score 1):

If the motor has no internal electronic commutator and you have successfully operated the motor by direct correction to a battery, you have confirmed that the motor is some type of commutator motor, not a motor that required a controller for brushless motors.

Any electronic speed controller (ESC) that works by reducing the voltage applied to the motor should work reasonably well. The specifics of the motor design, number of poles etc. will not interfere.

Simply reducing the motor speed has the disadvantage that the speed will vary somewhat due to the internal voltage drop in the motor resistance as the current varies due to load variations.

If you were to insert a variable series resistor to control the speed, that effect is more severe. Also the power dissipation in the resistor can be problematic.